# There is a "%{nas-name}" variable to get the current nas name and use into dialup.conf freeradius?

Tags: variables, freeradius

I am working with freeradius, I could install and configure it on linux server and I can receive request from remote devices but I need to make a change to the query that inserts into radacct table to save the name of the nas (for usage reports) but I can´t find something about it, this is really simple, I just need to know what variable to use, for example I know that I can use %{User-Name} variable to get the name of the user that is connecting to freeradius, I need a similar variable to get the nas name, that´s all.

I hope it exists and you can tell what it is.

Thanks in advance, have a nice day.

Comment: %n  || %{NAS-IP-Address}  is nas ip address, will that work?

Answer (score 0):

That's be `%{%{NAS-Identifier}:-%{client:shortname}}`